# How do I get email input and submit button on same line in MailChimp?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, mailchimp

I'm trying to get the "Email" input and "Submit" button to sit on the same line. Here's what it looks like:

[image: It's on separate lines and looks awkward]

So it should look like this (in regards to layout):

[image: Both the email and submit on same line]

You can see the actual page here: http://www.grainbeast.com/free-goods/

Can you tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide the HTML & CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following css to style.css

```
#mc4wp-form-1 > input[type="email"] {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and remove

`float: left`

from the submit button style so the html reads

```
<input type="submit" value="Get Free Access" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/00adpdb1/

Just wrap your input with "overflow:hidden" and pull to right button with "floar: right"

```css
 * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

 input {display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.57142857;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #cfd3cc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    margin: 0;
    }
    
    .btn {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.57142857;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
      background:red;
      color: #fff;
}

.pull-right {
  float:right;
}

.s-margin-left {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="pull-right btn btn-lg btn-primary s-margin-bottom s-margin-left" type="submit">send</button>
  <div style="overflow: hidden;">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter E-mail" value="" id="email" name="email">
  </div>
</div>
```